# Keyword calling a keyword from another file with variable - Robot Framework

Tags: python, testing, automation, robotframework

good morning!

I'm automating tests using Robot Framework with Sikulli Library.

I have the following problem, I don't even know how to do it:

I would like to create a keyword in a file with a Wait Until Screen Contain and then a click. The goal is to keep it standardized and not keep repeating it over and over again.

And in the other files create keywords using the keyword in the file. Then I would only add the keyword, I wouldn't need to add a wait and click.

Would?

First file example:

```
*** Keywords ***
clickButton
    Wait Until Screen Contain    ${IMAGE}.png    3
    Click    ${IMAGE}.png
```

Second file example:

```
*** Keywords ***
testOne
    clickButton     imageOne
```

The "imageOne" is the image name saved.

Waiting!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by importing the first file as a resource. Here is the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files). In your case it would look something like this:

file1.resource

```
*** Keywords ***
clickButton
[Arguments]    ${IMAGE}
    Wait Until Screen Contain    ${IMAGE}.png    3
    Click    ${IMAGE}.png
```

file2.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ${RESOURCES}/file1.resource
Resource    path/to/file/file1.resource
Resource    ${CURDIR}/path/file1.resource
Resource    file1.resource
etc
*** Keywords ***
testOne
    clickButton     imageOne
```

There are several options for importing the file. Use variable in the path, variable can be easily set when runnung the tests. Use absolute path, you can even use ${CURDIR}, or just with the file name if the files are in the same folder or you have it in your python path

> ${CURDIR}   An absolute path to the directory where the test data file
> is located.  This variable is case-sensitive.

Comment: Jiri, very thanks! You helped me a lot!!